# Timing out while updating MySQL with PHP from a CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv, cron, timeout

I need to come up with a way to make a large task faster to beat the timeout.

I have *very* limited access to the server due to the restrictions of the hosting company.

I have a system set up where a cron visits a PHP file that grabs a csv that contains data on some products.  The csv does not contain all of the fields that the product would have.  Just a handful of essential ones.

I've read a fair number of articles on timeouts and handling csv's and currently (in an attempt to shave time) I have made a table (let's call it csv_data) to hold the csv data.  I have a script that truncates the csv_data table then inserts data from the csv so each night the latest recordset from the csv is in that table (the csv file gets updated nightly).   So far, no timeout problems..the task only takes about 4-5 seconds.

The timeouts occur when I have to sift through the data to make updates to the products table. The steps that it is running right now is like this

```
1. Get the sku from csv_data table (that holds thousands of records)
2. Select * from Products where products.sku = csv.sku (products table also holds thousands of records to loop through)
3. Get numrows.   
    If numrows<0{no record in products, so skip}. 
    If numrows>1{duplicate entries, don't change anything, but later on report the sku}
    If numrows==1{Update selected fields in the products table with csv data}
4. Go to the next record in csv_data all over again
```

(I figured outlining the process is shorter and easier than dropping in the code.)
I looked into MySQl views and stored procedures but I am not skilled enough in it to know if it will handle the 'if' statement portion.

Is there anything I can do to make this faster to avoid the timeouts?

### **edit:**

I should mention that `set_time_limit(0);` isn't doing it. And if it helps, the server uses `IIS7` and `fastcgi`
Thanks for your help.

Update after using suggestions from Jakob and Shawn:

I'm doing something wrong.   The speed is definitely faster and the csv sku is incrementing,

but when I tried to implement Shawn's solution; the query is giving me a PHP Warning:  mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean error.

Can you help me spot what I am doing wrong?

Here is the section of code:

```
$csvdata="SELECT * FROM csv_update";
    $csvdata_result=mysql_query($csvdata); 
    mysql_query($csvdata);
    $csvdata_num = mysql_num_rows($csvdata_result);
    $i=0;       
while($i<$csvdata_num){

$csv_code=@mysql_result($csvdata_result,$i,"skucode");

$datacheck=NULL;    
$datacheck=substr($csv_code,0,1);

if($datacheck>='0' && $datacheck<='9'){

$csv_price=@mysql_result($csvdata_result,$i,"price");
$csv_retail=@mysql_result($csvdata_result,$i,"retail");
$csv_stock=@mysql_result($csvdata_result,$i,"stock");
$csv_weight=@mysql_result($csvdata_result,$i,"weight");
$csv_manufacturer=@mysql_result($csvdata_result,$i,"manufacturer");
$csv_misc1=@mysql_result($csvdata_result,$i,"misc1");
$csv_misc2=@mysql_result($csvdata_result,$i,"misc2");
$csv_selectlist=@mysql_result($csvdata_result,$i,"selectlist");
$csv_level5=@mysql_result($csvdata_result,$i,"level5");
$csv_frontpage=@mysql_result($csvdata_result,$i,"frontpage");
$csv_level3=@mysql_result($csvdata_result,$i,"level3");
$csv_minquantity=@mysql_result($csvdata_result,$i,"minquantity");
$csv_quantity1=@mysql_result($csvdata_result,$i,"quantity1");
$csv_discount1=@mysql_result($csvdata_result,$i,"discount1");
$csv_quantity2=@mysql_result($csvdata_result,$i,"quantity2");
$csv_discount2=@mysql_result($csvdata_result,$i,"discount2");
$csv_quantity3=@mysql_result($csvdata_result,$i,"quantity3");
$csv_discount3=@mysql_result($csvdata_result,$i,"discount3");

    $count_check="SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalCount FROM products WHERE skucode = '$csv_code'";
    $count_result=mysql_query($count_check); 
    mysql_query($count_check);
    $totalCount=@mysql_result($count_result,0,'totalCount');
    $loopCount = ceil($totalCount / 25);
    for($j = 0; $j < $loopCount; $j++){

    $prod_check="SELECT skucode FROM products WHERE skucode = '$csv_code' LIMIT ($loopCount*25), 25;";
    $prodresult=mysql_query($prod_check); 
    mysql_query($prod_check);
    $prodnum =@mysql_num_rows($prodresult);
    $prod_id=@mysql_result($prodresult,0,"catalogid");


    if($prodnum<1){ 
    echo "NOT FOUND:$csv_code<br>";
    $count_sku_not_found=$count_sku_not_found+1;
    $list_sku_not_found=$list_sku_not_found." $csv_code";}

    if($prodnum>1){ 
    echo "DUPLICATE:$csv_ccode<br>";    
    $count_duplicate_skus=$count_duplicate_skus+1;
    $list_duplicate_skus=$list_duplicate_skus." $csv_code";}


if ($prodnum==1){
///This prevents an overwrite from happening if the csv file doesn't produce properly
    if ($csv_price!="" OR $csv_price!=NULL)
    {$sql_price='price="'.$csv_price.'"';}

    if ($csv_retail!="" OR $csv_retail!=NULL)
    {$sql_retail=',retail="'.$csv_retail.'"';}

    if ($csv_stock!="" OR $csv_stock!=NULL)
    {$sql_stock=',stock="'.$csv_stock.'"';}

    if ($csv_weight!="" OR $csv_weight!=NULL)
    {$sql_weight=',weight="'.$csv_weight.'"';}

    if ($csv_manufacturer!="" OR $csv_manufacturer!=NULL)
    {$sql_manufacturer=',manufacturer="'.$csv_manufacturer.'"';}

    if ($csv_misc1!="" OR $csv_misc1!=NULL)
    {$sql_misc1=',misc1="'.$csv_misc1.'"';}

    if ($csv_misc2!="" OR $csv_misc2!=NULL)
    {$sql_pother2=',pother2="'.$csv_misc2.'"';}

    if ($csv_selectlist!="" OR $csv_selectlist!=NULL)
    {$sql_selectlist=',selectlist="'.$csv_selectlist.'"';}

    if ($csv_level5!="" OR $csv_level5!=NULL)
    {$sql_level5=',level5="'.$csv_level5.'"';}

    if ($csv_frontpage!="" OR $csv_frontpage!=NULL)
    {$sql_frontpage=',frontpage="'.$csv_frontpage.'"';}



$import="UPDATE products SET $sql_price $sql_retail $sql_stock $sql_weight $sql_manufacturer $sql_misc1 $sql_misc2 $sql_selectlist $sql_level5 $sql_frontpage    $sql_in_stock WHERE skucode='$csv_code'";
 mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error("error updating in products table"));


echo "Update ".$csv_code." successful ($i)<br>";

$count_success_update_skus=$count_success_update_skus+1;
$list_success_update_skus=$list_success_update_skus." $csv_code";



//empty out variables 
$sql_price='';
$sql_retail='';
$sql_stock='';
$sql_weight='';
$sql_manufacturer='';
$sql_misc1='';
$sql_misc2='';
$sql_selectlist='';
$sql_level5='';
$sql_frontpage='';
$sql_in_stock='';
$prodnum=0;

}
}
$i++;
}
```

Comment: Show your code so I can help suggest a "lazy load handler"

Comment: Never grab `*` when you don't have to (this depends on HOW much data you have per row too), if all you need is to know `numrows` just grab an id, or single value and test that way.

Comment: Jakub, thanks :)  I grabbed just the product.sku field and it dropped my time to about 1.5 minutes and I have beaten the timeout YAY!!!!! So thank you, you definitely helped improve it a lot. I am also going to implement Shawn's idea to see if I can get it faster because while 1.5 minutes is good, I can see the script needing more efficiency as more products get added to the csv

Comment: Sorry, that code is a mess in formatting and workflow. But if you speak of thousands of records that should not be a problem. Do you have an index on the SKU column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it timing out before the first row is returned or is it between rows during the read? One good practice bit would be to handle your query in chunks; do a count first to see how many records you are dealing with for the SKU, the loop through smaller chunks (the size of these chunks would depend on how many things you have to do with each row). Your updated workflow would look more like this:

1. Get next SKU from CSV
2. Get a total count: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalCount FROM products WHERE products.sku = csv.sku`
3. Determine chunk size (using 25 for this demo)
4. `loopCount = ceil(totalCount / 25)`
5. Loop through all results using a loop like this: `for($i = 0; $i < loopCount; $i++)`
6. Inside your loop you should be running a query like this: `SELECT * FROM products WHERE products.sku = csv.sku LIMIT (loopCount*25), 25`

You will want to use a constant order for your SELECT chunks; your unique ID would probably be best.

Comment: It's timing out between rows.  I've tested it using a csv with only 100 records and it works fine (slowish but fine).... I am going to try this method and see if that will fix it :)   I'll update soon.  Thanks Shawn

Comment: If it is timing out between rows the above solution should solve it. I am interested to know how to goes so please post back :). Also, it will probably be slightly slower for smaller files since you are doing multiple requests but you can tweak with the chunk size to find the best performance/reliability blend. Enjoy!

Comment: Hi Shawn, I'm still relatively new to stackoverflow so forgive me if I'm not doing this right.  I assumed (by the character limitation in the comment box) that I should edit your answer to put my reply into.

Comment: Dustin, usually people edit their own post and add a "SOLUTION:" section where they provide code snippets or such; this way when someone else finds the post they can quickly see how you solved it.

Comment: oops, I'll fix that now. (I just assumed I would edit the one you posted, that way if I had 6 or 7 different answers to the main post, it would be less confusing as to which solution I am working with.

Comment: Shawn, am I incorporating your workflow wrong?  I've updated the code in the original post

Comment: That's a big snippet :) I am just heading into a meeting now but I will try to review it later.

Comment: Everything looks sounds however why are you calling the mysql_query function twice everywhere you make a query? I do not develop in PHP full time but this seems very strange to me :) Example: $count_result=mysql_query($count_check); 
    mysql_query($count_check);

Comment: Honestly, it's what I learned from my first tutorial and used ever since.  From the way I understand it, the first time it is used, it's just assigning the results of the query to the variable.  The second time it is used, it's calling the actual query to be executed.   This is instead of using mysql_fetch_array

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this problem with cron. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron . It has never had timeout.

Comment: I wish I could cron.  Unfortunately, the access given by the webserver is extremely unlimited.