# Can one div trigger an ajax response to another div

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, triggers

What I am trying to have is a main page with 3 div areas and use ajax to call each area in sequence.  So, when the page loads, div1 will already be loading the page being called into it from ajax. (some heavy mysql work is being done on the page that is being called in).  When it is done, it will return the word "complete".

When this happens, I'd like ajax to trigger the next loading page into div 2 which will go through the process and return the word "complete" when it is finished.   Same procedure with the third.

Essentially, I have a big mysql data update being performed and PHP keeps timing out (I've maxed out execution time)   so my theory is...if I can limit the number of rows it processes (it can do 2000 rows without timing out)  then I would like it to process 2000 rows...finish..that div lets me know by returning the word "complete" and also initiates div 2  to work on the next batch of records.

I'm pretty certain this is not the best practice and I am looking into the possibility of stored procedures but this hypothesis seemed to be the most adequate given the time frame I have to find a remedy (once it is fixed, I have time to research and learn better methods)

I found an article that may or may not help.  I didn't quite understand it enough to do a multiple div reaction

[How can i change the contents of div x (with ajax) automatically when another ajax call is made changing the contents of div y?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151859/how-can-i-change-the-contents-of-div-x-with-ajax-automatically-when-another-aj)

I am hoping you can help.

### Thanks

Update:
Matej, can that be nested for 3 divs like this?
Can this be nested?

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "example.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "example2.php",
         data: { name: "Bill", location: "DC" }
         })
  .done(function( msg ) {
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "example.php",
                   data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
                    })
                .done(function( msg ) {
                 // HERE
                 });
        });
  });
```

---

Update

This sort of comes close to what I am looking for

```
 <head>
 <title>jQuery.load()</title>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div1").load("firstfile.php");
});
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="loadPage">Click To Load Web Page</a><br />
 <div id="div1" /></div>
<div id="div2" />on standby</div>
<div id="div3" />on standby</div>
<hr>

<script>
if ($('#div1:contains("Complete")').length > 0) {
    //load 2nd file in div 2
}

if ($('#div2:contains("Complete")').length > 0) {
        //load 3rd file in div 3
}
</script>
```

As a task is performed, it returns the word "Complete" which then triggers div 2 to load a page and when it was done it would return the word "Complete' and then trigger div 3 to load it's page.

One problem is that I can't get it to look at the innerHTML so the word "Complete" only works if the code is already in the page and not from a page load...and I am also kind of hoping that I can do this without requiring any text based trigger at all.

Ideally, I hope their is a way that the firstloadedpage.php can return something that either triggers div2 to go ahead or if it can send a signal to the parent, indicating the load is complete, and have the parent trigger div 2

Comment: Have you tried `set_time_limit()` in PHP to give you more time?

Comment: Yes, I have tried set_time_limit() and it solved it for a bit.   Then 
I encountered this problem before and had it resolved here
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231561/timing-out-while-updating-mysql-with-php-from-a-csv)   

So now I basically want to get a main page where div1 will call in the php file (from the linked article) which, when finished, will start div2 that will call in the same code but start from record 2000 to 4000

Comment: Rory, I haven't tried anything in terms of the main page with divs.   I can create a page and I can get ajax to populate a div field by loading another page into it and that's it.  I can't think of how to use that in order to set off the next div when the first is complete.   
I didn't know if I could just write a function at the bottom of the loaded page (in div1) that would call div2's ajax for me

Answer (score 1):

you can start next ajax function in complete callback of first one.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "example.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    // HERE
  });
```